# I have a TextView in MainActivity which I want to update from other activity?

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to do that?
In MainActivity I have a TEXTVIEW and a BUTTON while in another activity I  just have a BUTTON through which I want to update my TEXTVIEW in the MainActivity?
First the user will press the BUTTON in MainActivity to go to another activity from there as soon as user presses the BUTTON the MainActivity TEXTVIEW content should get updated.?

Help me guys I am doing this for whole day finally I need to post it here. I didn't get about that how to do this.
Updating textview in another activity from MainActivity  is easy but reverse is tedious

Comment: Hint: Callbacks... For reference, you can read about how to use Fragments to communicate with an Activity. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: Alternatively, you need to know how to pass results back from an Activity. Which is what the First App tutorial covers in the Android Documentation. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the second activity with startActivityForResult. When the user clicks the button in the second activity, you can put the data that you want in the Bundle and set it with setResult and that bundle will be passed to onActivityResult of your first Activity.

In your future question, please provide the code. I could have answered with the code that you need if you had provided any.

Here you have the example with this behavior: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Also, the comment of @cricket_007 with the link to the training is more than recommended.